# Numpy Vectorization - Weird issue

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am performing some vectorized calculation using numpy. I was investigating a bug I am having and I ended with this line:

```
(vertices[:,:,:,0]+vertices[:,:,:,1]*256)*4
```

The result was expected to be `100728` for the index `vertices[0,0,17]`, however, I am getting `35192`.
When I tried to change it into `4.0` instead of `4`, I ended getting the correct value of `100728` and thus fixing my bug.

I would like to understand why the floating point matters here especially that I am using python 3.7 and it is multiplication, not even division.

Extra information:

```
vertices.shape=(203759, 12, 32, 3)
python==3.7
numpy==1.16.1
```

Edit 1:

- vertices type is "numpy.uint8"
- vertices[0, 0, 17] =>  [94, 98, 63]

Comment: What is the type of the values in vertices?

Comment: Also if you could provide some samples of data where it fails it would be helpful. What values are in `vertices[0,0,17]`?

Comment: the vertices type is "numpy.uint8"

Comment: vertices[0, 0, 17] is [94, 98, 63]

Comment: as a hint: 100728 % 2^16 = 35192

Comment: @Kasparov92, what do you mean by `vertices[0, 0, 17] => [94, 98, 63]` ?

Comment: @Aaron gave you the solution: try to change the type to uint16 or uint32

Comment: I used '4.0' and I am fine with it, I was seeking explanation and @Aaron made me get to the ahaaaa moment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using too small integers, and the number overflows and wraps around because numpy uses fixed width integers rather than infinite precision like python `int`'s. Numpy will ["promote"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) the type of a result based on the inputs, but it won't promote the result based on whether an overflow happens or not (it's done before the actual calculation.

In this case when you multiply:  `vertices[:,:,:,1]*256` (I shall call this `A`), 256 cannot be held in a `uint8`, so it goes to the next higher type: `uint16` this allows the result of the multiplication to hold the correct value in this case, because the maximum possible value of any element in `verticies` is 255, so the largest value possible is 255*256, which fits just fine in a 16 bit uint.

Then you add `vertices[:,:,:,0] + A` (I shall call this `B`). if the largest value of `A` was 255*256, and the largest value of `vertices[:,:,:,0]` is 255 (again the largest value of a `uint8`), the largest sum of the two is equal to 2<sup>16</sup>-1 (the largest value you can hold in a 16 bit unsigned int). This is still fine right up until you go for your last multiplication.

When you get to `B * 4`, numpy again has to decide what the return type should be. The integer 4 easily fits in a `uint16`, so numpy does not promote the type higher still to a `uint32` or `uint64` because it does not preemptively avoid overflows as previously described. This results in any multiplication products greater than 2<sup>16</sup>-1 being returned as modulo 2<sup>16</sup>.

If you instead use a floating point number (`4. or 4.0`), numpy sees this as a "higher" value type that cannot fit inside a `uint16`, so it promotes the result to floating point, which can accomodate much higher numbers without overflowing.

If you don't want to change the entire array: `verticies` to a larger dtype, you could simply take the result `B` and convert that before you multiply by 4 as such: `B.astype(np.uint64) * 4`. This will allow you to hold *much* larger values without overflowing (though it does not actually eliminate the problem if the value is larger than 4 ever).

Comment: the link you've pointed to says "When both scalars and arrays are used, the array’s type takes precedence". Doesn't it mean that in `(A * 256)`, the `uint8` of `A` will take precedence over the `uint16` of the scalar `256` ? Not sure what "takes precedence" means here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I appreciate your time explaining and pointing to the reasons (Y)

Comment: @fountainhead I think they mean takes precedence in how they determine int, float, or other. The example shows a situation where a float might be cast to an int if it can be done exactly, which highlights the difference from c/c++ type casting rules. It could definitely be explained a little clearer.